# C "Expected Expression" error with Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile this code example from the book "Head First C" (page 50), and Xcode gives me the error "Parse Issue" "Expected Expression" and highlights the line "int longitude = -64;" in red.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void go_south_east(int * lat, int * lon)
{    
    *lat = *lat - 1;
    *lon = *lon + 1;
}

int main()
{
   int latitude = 32;
   int longitude = -64;
   ￼￼go_south_east(&latitude￼,&longitude);
   printf("Avast! Now at: [%i, %i]\n", latitude, longitude);
   return 0;
}
```

I have no idea why.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you copy and paste the code or did you type it in manually? It could be a foreign space character.

Comment: I copied and pasted most of it with a little bit of manual typing.  I didn't see that blank character.  Where do you see that at?  Thank you.

Comment: Retype that line manually and recompile.

Comment: In more-recent versions of Xcode (I'm checking Xcode 5.1.1 with LLVM 5.1), this error shows up as the much-more-helpful **“Non-ASCII characters are not allowed outside of literals and identifiers”**.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Sometimes when copying code from PDFs **invisible** unwanted characters are copied as well.

To fix this you can tell Xcode to show you all invisible characters by changing the editor properties from the top bar menu.

```
(top bar menu) → Editor → Show Invisibles
```

You will have to delete anything that looks strange strange, like a space being represented by an actual space (" ") or a little triangle ("^"). **Keep in mind that in this mode spaces are represented with this symbol "⌴".**

For example:

[image: Sample invisible bad character]

Which causes the "Expected Expression" error.

Comment: There was an extra space that showed up when I did that showed up after "&latitude￼".  Deleting it fixed the code.  Thanks to all!  I will be more careful when coping code from PDFs in the future.  Rookie mistake I know.  But I had been trying to solve it for a longtime now, and I was about to give up.

Comment: You probably did the same thing I did!  I entered a ^S to save the document, but that actually entered a ^S character!